# How to load a lib folder in aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In Serverless, I have the following folder structure

```
/component_a/function_1/function_1.js
/component_a/lib/util.js
```

When I try to load util.js from function_1.js using

```
u = require('../lib/util.js')
```

it works from the serverless CLI "serverless function run function_1". However in lambda/api-gateway it cannot find lib/util.js .

This is the error "Error: Cannot find module '../lib/util'"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to fix. In the component_a/s-function.json replace

```
"handler": "handler.handler",
```

with

```
"handler": "component_a/handler.handler",
```

in the function_1.js call the util.js like

```
u = require('../lib/util')
```

from the Serverless documentation

> The handler property gives you the ability to share code between your
>   functions. By default the handler property is handler.handler, that
>   means it's only relative to the function folder, so only the function
>   folder will be deployed to Lambda.
>
> If however you want to include the parent subfolder of a function, you
>   should change the handler to be like this:
>   **functionName/handler.handler** 
>   As you can see, the path to the handler
>   now includes the function folder, which means that the path is now
>   relative to the parent subfolder, so in that case the parent subfolder
>   will be deployed along with your function. So if you have a lib folder
>   in that parent subfolder that is required by your function, it'll be
>   deployed with your function.
>
> This also gives you the ability to handle npm dependencies however you
>   like. If you have a package.json and node_modules in that parent
>   subfolder, it'll be included in the deployed lambda. So the more
>   parent folders you include in the handler path, the higher you go in
>   the file tree.